# Second image of the slider appears on the visibile area of the first image

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have slider of images which works on jquery. I have problem that after loading or reloading the page second image of the slider appears on the visibile area of the first image. Looks like this: 
[image]

But when I click on the arrow to see the next image and then go back to the first image it appears as it needed without visiblle second image. Looks like it need to be after loading the page: [image]

So, what I need to change that after loading the page my slider look like on the second screenshot?

HTML(using bootstrap 4):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Slider</title>
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/32b3e97fa6.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <h1 class="col-12 text-center header">Slider</h1>
        <div class="list-border">
    <ul class="row images-list">
        <li class="images-item">
            <img src="images/image_1.png" alt="First image">
            <a class="next" href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </li>
        <li class="images-item">
            <img src="images/image_2.png" alt="Second image">
            <a class="previous" href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            <a class="next" href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </li>
        <li class="images-item">
            <img src="images/image_3.png" alt="Third image">
            <a class="previous" href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            <a class="next" href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </li>
        <li class="images-item">
            <img src="images/image_4.png" alt="Fourth image">
            <a class="previous" href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            <a class="next" href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </li>
        <li class="images-item">
            <img src="images/image_5.png" alt="Fifth image">
            <a class="previous" href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            <a class="next" href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </li>
        <li class="images-item">
            <img src="images/image_6.png" alt="Sixth image">
            <a class="previous" href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            <a class="next" href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </li>
        <li class="images-item">
            <img src="images/image_7.png" alt="Seventh image">
            <a class="previous" href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            <a class="back-to-start" href="#"><i class="fa fa-refresh" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
        integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Sass:

```
@import "../css/normalize.css";

.header {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.list-border {
  border:1px solid #666666;
  border-radius:6px;
  padding:13px;
  clear:both;
  background:#ebebeb;
  box-shadow: 0px 45px 100px -32px #000;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;

  .images-item {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;

    .next {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 89%;
    }

    .previous {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 1%;
    }

    .back-to-start {
      position:absolute;
      bottom: 36%;
      left: 88%;


    }

    .fa {
      font-size: 2rem;
      color: #ffffff;
      background-color: rgba(51, 72, 93, 0.5);
      padding: 15px 20px;
      border-radius: 100%;

      &:hover {
        color: #2bcb72;
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
        transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
      }
    }
  }

}
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var image = $('ul li img');
    var width = image.width();

    $('ul').wrap('<div id="list-wrapper"/>');

    $('#list-wrapper').css({
        width: function () {
            return width;
        },

        height: function () {
            return image.height();
        },

        position: 'relative',
        overflow: 'hidden',
        padding: '0'

    });

    //Get total of image sizes and set as width of ul
    var totalWidth = image.length * width;
    $('ul').css({
        width: function () {
            return totalWidth;
        }
    });

    $(image).each ( //looking for each of our images in the list
        function (intIndex) {
            $(this).nextAll('a').bind("click", function () { //finding all anchors tags next to the images
                if($(this).is(".next")) {
                    $(this).parent('li').parent('ul').animate({
                        "margin-left": (-(intIndex + 1) * width)
                    },800)
                } else if($(this).is(".previous")) {
                    $(this).parent('li').parent('ul').animate({
                        "margin-left": (-(intIndex - 1) * width)
                    }, 800)
                    } else if ($(this).is(".back-to-start")){
                    $(this).parent('li').parent('ul').animate({
                        "margin-left": (0)
                    }, 800)
                }
            });
        });
});
```

Comment: Could you make a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)? And just for curiosity, why don't you use the [Bootstrap carousel](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved, it consisted in the fact that in the bootstrap class `.row` there are margins left and right. 
**Solution:** add `margin-left: 0;` to the class `.images-list`.